# Trouble changing outputFormat in mvn dependency:tree

Tags: java, maven, dependencies

As described [here](http://www.summa-tech.com/blog/2011/04/12/a-visual-maven-dependency-tree-view/) it is possible to display the dependency-output in graphml format with the following command:

```
dependency:tree -DoutputType=graphml -DoutputFile=dependencygraphml
```

But, no mater what value I enter for `outputType` the output in file does not change. Maven says they support "text, dot, graphml and tgf" [here](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/tree-mojo.html#outputType). Currently I have no idea what I am doing wrong.

By the way I am working with maven 3.0.0 . Any ideas what I could check?

Comment: Solution: as described here: http://java.dzone.com/articles/visualize-maven-project I have to manually set my dependency to of dependency plugin to 2.4. Maven 3.0. seems to be shipped with 2.1. as default

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As you posted in the comments here and at dzone, one has to specify a recent enough version of the plugin. Otherwise an old version might get used, which doesn't support graphml yet.

This can be done like this:

```
mvn org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:2.4:tree -DoutputFile=deps.graphml -DoutputType=graphml
```